# PHP and Jquery pass value from form. Update function on DataBase

Tags: plugins, php, jquery

i do loop foreach:

```
<?php  $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_myprojects" ); ?>
<form  id="aad-form2" action="" method="POST">
<?php foreach($myrows as $a): ?>

<input id="id" type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $a->id; ?>">
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $a->name; ?>">
<input id="header" type="text" name="header" value="<?php echo $a->header; ?>">
<input id="body" type="text" name="body" value="<?php echo $a->body; ?>">
<input id="urls" type="text" name="urls" value="<?php echo $a->urls; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="aad-submit2" id="aad_submit2" class="button- primary"value="<?php _e('Update', 'aad'); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo admin_url('/images/wpspin_light.gif'); ?>" class="waiting" id="aad_loading2" style="display:none;"/>
<br />

<?php endforeach ?>
</form>
```

And my jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#aad-form2').submit(function(){
//alert('test');
$('#aad_loading2').show();
$('#aad_submit2').attr('disabled', true);
data2 = {
action: 'aad_get_results2',
form_data2: $('#aad-form2').serialize()
//aad_nonce: aad_vars.aad_nonce
};

$.post(ajaxurl, data2, function (response) {
$('#aad_results').html(response);
$('#aad_loading2').hide();
$('#aad_submit2').attr('disabled', false);
}); 
return false;
});
});
```

And when i do action only last form is update in data base.
Example i have 5 records in database. Foreach print me 5 forms, but when i click submit button record 1 or record 2 nothing happen.

Only last record from loop is update. Help

Tell me why? Probaly i don't now jquery saw good :) Help me.

My update function in plugin:

```
function aad_process2_ajax() {
global $wpdb;
parse_str($_POST['form_data2'], $form_data2);
echo $id = $form_data2['id'];
echo $name = $form_data2['name'];
echo $header = $form_data2['header'];
echo $body = $form_data2['body'];
echo $urls = $form_data2['urls'];
$wpdb->update('wp_myprojects', array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name, 'header'=>$header, 'body'=>$body, 'urls'=>$urls), array('id'=>$id));
$wpdb->show_errors();
/*EVRY PROCESS AJAX MUST DIE!!!!*/
die();
/*EVRY PROCESS AJAX MUST DIE!!!!*/
}
add_action('wp_ajax_aad_get_results2','aad_process2_ajax');
```

Comment: please could you post also `aad_get_results2` action in your functions.php?

Comment: Ok, add too question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each set of form fields has the same set of field names (`[...]` is the rest of your code):

```
<?php foreach ( $myrows as $a ): ?>

    <input id="id" type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $a->id; ?>">

    [...]

<?php endforeach ?>
```

If 3 rows are returned in `$myrows` and the values are `fee, fie, foe`, the value attribute changes for each field, but the field name is always the same. Here is are the first 3 fields bunched together:

```
<input id="id" type="text" name="id" value="fee">
<input id="id" type="text" name="id" value="fie">
<input id="id" type="text" name="id" value="foe">
```

The web server sees only the last value: `id = foe` `fee` and `fum` do not matter.

So, each set of form fields is replaced by the previous set. Define a unique name for each loop. Here is the first form field:

```
<?php
$row_count = 0;
foreach ( $myrows as $a ): ?>

    <input id="id-<?php echo $row_count; ?>" type="text" name="id-<?php echo $row_count; ?>" value="<?php echo $a->id; ?>">

    [ ... ]

    <?php
    $row_count++;
endforeach; ?>
```

Replace `[ ... ]` with you other code.

Now, those same 3 fields would look like this:

```
<input id="id-0" type="text" name="id-0" value="fee">
<input id="id-1" type="text" name="id-1" value="fee">
<input id="id-2" type="text" name="id-2" value="fee">
```

You can define the row count in a hidden form variable (outside the foreach loop).

```
<input type="hidden" name="row_count" value="<?php echo count( $myrows );">
```

Then, in `aad_process2_ajax()` loop through all the names and do as many updates as there are rows in the `row_count` form field.

Comment: this is hard too understand too me

Comment: Is any part of it clear?

Comment: Never mind i do in difrent why. And i i don't use jquery. Thx anywhy i fink u answer is correct.